# Flutter: Android notification icon displays white

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, android-push-notification, launcher-icon

I'm using **flutter_launcher_icons** package to generate launcher icons for the apps. Everything works as expected, the launchers are generated and set for Android and iOS. However, on **Android push notifications**, the launcher is displayed as a white square, even though the icon is black.

I tried to add the icon as meta-data on the manifest file as well as with the Notification builder as a small icon, the result is the same.

Here's the output from my pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter_icons:
android: true
ios: true
image_path_android: "assets/icon/ic_logo_new.png"
image_path_ios: "assets/icon/ic_logo_new.png"
remove_alpha_ios: true
adaptive_icon_background: "assets/icon/ic_launcher_background.png"
adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icon/ic_logo_new.png"
```

Is there anyone who faced this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

just add custom icon to incoming notification.

Just add a meta-data inside tag in your manifest file.
[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="When Coin"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
   android:resource="@mipmap/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I've tried this, no luck(

Comment: @Laura your icon should be ransparent because All colors and non transparent pixels are displayed in white  you can also refer this link [https://clevertap.com/blog/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/]

Comment: my icons are transparent, that's why the issue occurs when trying to add adaptive icons